# Mongodb counts from two stages

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregate

I have got this situation.
I need number of total records. Then apply filter, and then I need filtered products and number of filtered products.

here is my query:

```
let result = await Product.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: null, totalRecords: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $match: queries },
    { $group: { _id: null, filteredRecords: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $project: {
        name: 1,
        description: 1,
        smallImage: 1,
        rPriceTM: 1,
        discount: 1,
        discountRate: 1,
        dPriceTM: 1,
        isNewProduct: 1
    } },
    { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
    { $skip: (currentPage - 1) * productsPerPage },
    { $limit: productsPerPage }
])
```

the result:
`[ { _id: null } ]`

if I omit the `{ $group: {} }` stages, it works fine; the query gives me filtered array of products.

Please help me improve the query.

Comment: What is your expected result? The reason why is the `$group` have transform into new result, thus after your `$match` stage, it won't return any document.

Comment: number of totalRecords,
array of filtered products,
number of filteredRecords

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your current query is not working as the stages in the pipeline are dependent, which means the stages will perform the action based on the result returned from the previous stage.

For your scenario, you need separate/multiple pipelines to calculate `totalRecords`, `filteredRecords` and `data`. Thus, the [`$facet`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage is needed. At the last stage, you need the `$project` stage to decorate the final output document from the result returned from the `$facet` stage.

```
let result = await Product.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      totalRecords: [
        {
          $count: "total"
        }
      ],
      filteredRecords: [
        {
          $match: queries
        },
        {
          $count: "total"
        }
      ],
      data: [
        {
          $match: queries
        },
        {
          $project: {
            name: 1,
            description: 1,
            smallImage: 1,
            rPriceTM: 1,
            discount: 1,
            discountRate: 1,
            dPriceTM: 1,
            isNewProduct: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            _id: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $skip: (currentPage - 1) * productsPerPage
        },
        {
          $limit: productsPerPage
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      totalRecords: {
        $getField: {
          input: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$totalRecords",
              0
            ]
          },
          field: "total"
        }
      },
      filteredRecords: {
        $getField: {
          input: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$filteredRecords",
              0
            ]
          },
          field: "total"
        }
      },
      data: "$data"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hzf2TrCWWrZ)